# Geting CSS 404 errors with Litespeed Cache plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching, litespeed

I have a WordPress site hosted on Cloudways with the Litespeed Cache plugin installed. For some reason, I keep getting 404 errors for CSS URLs.

I have tried disabling CSS optimizations and purging cache, but nothing works. I even tried deactivating the LiteSpeed Cache plugin, but even that didn't work.

Any idea what might be causing this? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: CSS 404 Errors]